# extract words from a file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to create a dictionary of words from a collection of files.  Is there a simple way to print all the words in a file, one per line?

Comment: Do you need a certain programming language?

Comment: @mkmurray, "shell", "scripting" and "unix" usually means any of the tools available on standard UNIX boxes - awk, grep, sed, perl, cut and so on.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use `grep`:

- `-E '\w+'` searches for words
- `-o` only prints the portion of the line that matches

```
% cat temp
Some examples use "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog,"
rather than "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
for example text.
# if you don't care whether words repeat
% grep -o -E '\w+' temp
Some
examples
use
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
rather
than
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
for
example
text
```

If you want to only print each word once, disregarding case, you can use `sort`

- `-u` only prints each word once
- `-f` tells `sort` to ignore case when comparing words

```
# if you only want each word once
% grep -o -E '\w+' temp | sort -u -f
adipiscing
amet
brown
consectetur
dog
dolor
elit
example
examples
for
fox
ipsum
jumped
lazy
Lorem
over
quick
rather
sit
Some
text
than
The
use
```

Comment: thanks! I've been google for an hour for this. Strangely, using "... from a document" instead of "... from a text file" brought me this question as the first match

Comment: you can use ---->   grep -o -E '\w+'  testfile.txt  | sort -u -f |tee  5.txt   <----to wirte output to a file

Comment: jack yang: or just use a normal shell redirect `grep ... | sort -u -f > 5.txt`

Answer (score 3):

A good start is to simply use `sed` to replace all spaces with newlines, strip out the empty lines (again with `sed`), then `sort` with the `-u` (uniquify) flag to remove duplicates, as in this example:

```
$ echo "the quick brown dog and fox jumped
over the lazy   dog" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed '/^$/d' | sort -u

and
brown
dog
fox
jumped
lazy
over
quick
the
```

Then you can start worrying about punctuation and the likes.

Answer (score 3):

assuming words separated by white spaces

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' file
```

or

```
 tr ' ' "\n" < file
```

if you want uniqueness:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)_[$i]++}END{for(i in _) print i}' file

tr ' ' "\n" < file | sort -u
```

with some punctuations removed.

```
awk '{
    gsub(/["*^&()#@$,?~]/,"")
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){  _[$i]  }
}
END{    for(o in _){ print o }  }' file
```

Comment: uniqueness without waiting: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(!_[$i]) { print $i; _[$i]=1} }' file`

Answer (score 1):

[Ken Church's "Unix(TM) for Poets" (PDF)](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~padro/Unixforpoets.pdf) describes exactly this type of application - extracting words out of text files, sorting and counting them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The tr command can do this...

```
tr [:blank:] '\n' < test.txt
```

This asks the tr program to replace white space with a new line. The output is stdout, but it could be redirected to another file, result.txt:

```
tr [:blank:] '\n' < test.txt > result.txt
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318316/extract-words-from-files).