# Extract words from files

Tags: bash, extract

How can I extract all the words from a file, every word on a single line?
Example:

test.txt

```
This is my sample text
```

Output:

```
This
is
my
sample
text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tr command can do this...

```
tr [:blank:] '\n' < test.txt
```

This asks the `tr` program to replace white space with a new line.
The output is stdout, but it could be redirected to another file, result.txt:

```
tr [:blank:] '\n' < test.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: @Chistopher a small quibble - you might want to add `-s` to squeeze the white space.

Answer (score 1):

And here the obvious bash line:

```
for i in $(< test.txt)
do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

**EDIT** Still shorter:

```
printf '%s\n' $(< test.txt)
```

That's all there is to it, no special (pathetic) cases included (And handling multiple subsequent word separators / leading / trailing separators is by Doing The Right Thing (TM)). You can adjust the notion of a word separator using the $IFS variable, see bash manual.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer doesn't handle multiple spaces and such very well. An alternative would be

```
perl -p -e '$_ = join("\n",split);' test.txt
```

which would. E.g.

```
esben@mosegris:~/ange/linova/build master $ echo "test    test" | tr [:blank:] '\n' 
test



test
```

But

```
esben@mosegris:~/ange/linova/build master $ echo "test    test" | perl -p -e '$_ = join("\n",split);' 
test
test
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# echo -e "this     is\tmy\nsample text" | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g'           
this
is
my
sample
text
```

Answer (score 0):

perl answer will be :

```
pearl.214> cat file1
a b c d e f pearl.215> perl -p -e 's/ /\n/g' file1
a
b
c
d
e
f
pearl.216>
```