# How can I build a regexp in vim which searches for words which do not begin with "@"?

Tags: regex, search, vim

I would like to extract the usernames from a long text file built from Twitter posts. I have tried with expressions such as

```
:%s#\([^@].\{-}\) ##g
:%s#\(\<[^@].\{-}\>\) ##g
```

but it doesn't work. I read Vim's documentation for `@`, but, as far as I know, it applies to an escaped `@`, not a plain `@`.

How would I build an expression which erases the words which do not begin with "@"?

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Possibly related post: [Remove everything except regex match in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503748/remove-everything-except-regex-match-in-vim/4521486)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex in vim:

```
@\@<!\<\w\+\>
```

This will match all words that are not preceded by `@` character.

To match all non-space characters not preceded by `@` character use:

```
@\@<!\<\S\+\>
```

`\@<!` is the syntax for using negative lookbehind in `vim` which is equivalent of `(?<!@)` otherwise.

Comment: You can leave off the unnecessary grouping `\(...\)` here, as `@` is a single atom. Makes it slightly easier to read and type.

Comment: Better escape that `+` to make it `\+` unless you plan on using `\v`. e.g. `:%s/\v\@@<!<\w+>//g`. See `:h /\v` for more on magic

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I would appreciate very much if you point me to any good document about this. You now, my regexp level is more or less what is contained in http://vimregex.com/. For sure I am not a vim ninja :/

Comment: You can check [this post](http://ssiaf.blogspot.com/2009/07/negative-lookbehind-in-vim.html) and [this post](http://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/). Also if it worked out then you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you want to do this in vim.
I assume you have a unix/linux OS as you mention vim. 
Thanks to [extract words from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123572/extract-words-from-a-file) I found the following solution:

```
grep -o -E '@\w+' twitterlog.txt > usernames.txt
```

Comment: Just because someone mentions vim does *NOT* tie them to *nix. It runs on [a large number of non-*nix platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Availability).

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks "How can I remove everything not matching some pattern?".

I want to answer "How do I capture all the matches (and delete the contents of buffer and paste the matches)?"

#### Why not "remove everything not matching some pattern"?

Regex's are good at matching patterns, however not matching is trickier. Sure sometimes you can use negative look-aheads and look-behinds, but not every case is so straight forward. Matching exactly what you want is far easier. However if you do want to do it here is as close as I can get without breaking my brain:

```
:%s/.\&\(@\w*\)\@<![^@]//g
```

Note: this leaves trailing spaces and blank lines

#### Overview

The idea is to capture each match via `:s` and in the replacement execute an expression that will build up the matches into a register. Then delete, `:d`, all the lines and paste the register with the matches back to the register.

#### The How

```
:let @a = ""
:%s/@\w\+/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/n
:%d_
:%pu a
:1d_
```

#### Glory of details

- Clear the `a` register via `let @a = ""`
- Match the twitter users via `@\w\+` pattern
- Use `\=` inside the replacement of the `:s` to execute an expression
- use `setreg()` to set the value of the register
- using a capital register will append instead of replace
- `submatch(0)` yields the matched content
- using the 3rd parameter value of `'l'` specifies to append matches line-wise
- using the `n` flag will prevent the buffer from being altered (optional)
- `:%d_` delete entire buffer to the black hole register
- `:pu a` will put the a register
- `:1d_` will remove the empty first line

#### Well that is great but it is so much to type...

It may be a bunch to type compared to `:%!grep -E -o '@\w+'`, but it is a pure vim solution. We can shorten into a single line if that would be better

```
:let @a = "" | %s/@\w\+/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/n | %d_ | %pu a | 1d_
```

Probably not if you have to do anything like this on a regular basis. Here is a quick n' dirty command to put in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
" Extractomatic
" Replace the current buffer with each match on seperate line
" Usage:
"     :Extractomatic/pattern/
command! -nargs=+ Extractomatic
      \ let s:var = @a |
      \ let  @a = "" |
      \ %s<args>\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/n |
      \ %d_ |
      \ %pu a |
      \ 1d_ |
      \ let @a = s:var
```

Now you can just do `:Extractomatic/@\w\+/`.

However there are more robust solutions to this like Ingo Karkat's [Extract Matches](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795) plugin and the [Yankitute](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-yankitute) plugin.

#### Conclusion

Personally whichever way you want to use to solve this problem is good. However knowing how to use `:s` with a sub-replace-expression is a great way to level up your vim-script-fu

#### More help

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h submatch(
:h setreg(
:h registers
:h :d
:h :pu
:h range
```