# script to read a file with many columns into a file with one column

Tags: awk

For example if I have a file as follow:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10  11  12
```

And I want to reorganize this file as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Can I use the `awk` command for that or not?

Comment: Seen this: [I'm trying to create a dictionary of words from a collection of files. Is there a simple way to print all the words in a file, one per line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123572/extract-words-from-a-file) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

With `grep`:

```
grep -oE "[0-9]+" file
```

- The `-o` flag prints only the matching patterns (the digits in this case), delimited by newline
- `-E` activates extended regular expressions.

---

With `awk`:

```
awk 'OFS="\n"{$1=$1}1' file
```

- `OFS` defines the output field separator.
- `$1=$1` because we changed the OFS, we need to rebuild the line by setting the first field to itself, this will force the rebuild.
- `1` at least we need a true condition that the line is printed.

Comment: Could you please explain the command? For example what does -oE do in grep? what dose OFS mean? Sorry I am really beginner...

Comment: I prefer awk command and recently I find it super useful in my work... Thanks a lot and this awk can do my job and I will figure out the meaning or this sentence...

Comment: @Sky I added explantions to my answer

Comment: thanks! I will try to work more on awk.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
TMP$ sed -r 's/ +/\n/g' File
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Replace all continuous spaces with newline.

Comment: Thanks! But this commend will create one empty line in between the data from different column. awk 'OFS="\n"{$1=$1}1' gives one column without any empty line.

Comment: That's possibly because each line is terminating with one or more space...

Answer (score 0):

The naive AWK approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i; }
```

Chaos's approach is probably more efficient.

Comment: but yours is easier to read... thanks!